# Returning the same generated UUID in a static and non-static method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an object which is defined like so:

**TestDriver.java**

```
public void TestDriver extends FirefoxDriver implements SupportDownloads{

    public TestDriver(){
        super(TestDriver.service(), TestDriver.options());
    }

    private static service(){
        // implementation
    }

    private static options(){
        ..
        // attempting to generate a UUID which will be eventually be set as the folder where all downloads will go to. 
        // unique paths are needed as we will be using this class for multi-threaded runs and would like each browser to have its own unique download folder
        byte[] value = String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()).getBytes());
        String uniqueID = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(value).toString();
        ..
    }

    // purpose of this method is to return the path download folder 
    // note the repeated generation of the UUID because the above methods are static
    @Override
    public File getDownloadPath(){
        String value = String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        return new File(prop.getProperty(fileDirectory()) + File.separator + UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(value.getBytes()));    
    }
}
```

**SupportsDownload.java**

```
public interface SupportsDownload {
    public File getDownloadPath();
}
```

What I am trying to do is:

1. To generate a UUID so that each thread created have unique download paths
2. To be able to also return this UUID in a public method which is accessible outside of this class (for unit-testing purposes and usage by the users)

Even though the above code is already working, I will run into an issue which [official Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()) mention:

> Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a positive long number generated when this thread was created. The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime. **When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.**

As such, the above method is not foolproof because basing the UUID seed only on Thread.currentThread().getId() may yield the same ID if it is reused, causing the UUID generated to be the same.

I then tried to modify it to include time in millis, i.e.:

```
        byte[] value = String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId() + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()).getBytes());
```

However, as time value always changes, I wouldn't be able to grab the exact same value in the return method `getDownloadPath()`.

If I were to generate the time value once, and store it in a variable, i.e.:

`private final long timeInMillis = Calendar.getTime().getTimeInMillis();`

I will not be able to utilize this variable for both the static and non-static methods.

I'm at a loss, any suggestions would be great :-)

Comment: Try `ThreadLocal`

Comment: Maybe you should explain what your UUID should be used for? Making a UUID the same for 2 different scenarios actually makes it a non-UUID. If different threads (despite their id) should have the same UUID for the same file, use the filename as seed for the UUID.

Comment: Hi @dognose, I will be assigning the UUID to be the web driver's download folder, i.e. C:\...\target\c4ca4238-a0b9-3382-8dcc-509a6f75849b. So all downloaded files will be placed there. The UUID will be unique per instantiated driver, so it won't be used for 2 different scenarios.

Comment: I think your requirement is irrational: You want the SAME uuid for "File A" no matter if accessed from a certain thread or in the static method - but in another thread it should be another uuid?... So, you are demanding `UUID_static == UUID_t1`, `UUID_static == UUID_t2` but `UUID_t2 != UUID_t1`...?

Comment: Hello @dognose, thanks for the comment. Sorry, I don't understand, perhaps I was being unclear. The UUID will be used as the name of the folder where all files after being downloaded by a webdriver will be placed in. If we have 1 driver with UUID to be 'abcd-efgh', a folder called 'abcd-efgh' will be created, and all files downloaded will be directed into that folder. If we have 2 drivers, with 'abcd-efgh' and 'qwer-tayu' being the UUIDs for each driver respectively, then the files downloaded will go into these two folders respectively, depending on which driver was downloading the files.

Comment: The issue I'm facing is that I'm having difficulty thinking of a way where I access and return this generated UUID via getDownloadPath().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use `ThreadLocal` to do your task. Below I have added a sample code.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            MyUUIDFactory.getUUIDPerThread();
            MyUUIDFactory.getUUIDPerThread();
        }, "My Thread-1");

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            MyUUIDFactory.getUUIDPerThread();
            MyUUIDFactory.getUUIDPerThread();
        }, "My Thread-2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}

class MyUUIDFactory {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> localWebDriver = ThreadLocal.withInitial(
            () -> UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    public static String getUUIDPerThread() {
        return localWebDriver.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, this looks interesting -- let me give this a go.

Comment: @TimothyT. Sure. Let me know if you have any query or concerns.